# How do elections determine who is "leading" or "elected" with partial results?

Tags: election, canada

Every time a provincial or federal election comes on here in Toronto, we look at the partial results and report on "leading/elected".

I've never understood how this is calculated. How do the major news sites who provide these statistics determine when to call a riding "elected" with one leader as opposed to "leading" with only 25% of results in?

Answer (score 2):

It's a [statistical extrapolation](http://www.cnn.com/2010/POLITICS/09/20/projection.explainer/index.html) based on exit polling and the partial vote tallies.